# Namespace alias inside classes alternative

Tags: c++, namespaces, refactoring, alias, using

do you know if it is possible to simulate a kind of namespace alias inside classes? I know that you cannot declare namespaces inside classes, but is there something other alternative?

I give you an example:

```
namespace NamespaceA
    {
    typedef int Type;
    enum : int
      {
      NONE,
      A,
      B,
      C
     };
    }

  namespace NamespaceB = NamespaceA; // Ok
  struct Test
    {
    namespace NamespaceC = NamespaceA; // Compile time error

    void f()
      {
      NamespaceC::Type makeMeWork = NamespaceC::A;
      }
    };
```

I don't want to use enum classes because of some other constraints.

Thanks!

Comment: what are the other constraints? why do you want an alias? how is `NamespaceC::Type` better than `NamespaceA::Type` ?

Comment: Other constraints: classes that uses that "enum" can have both values expressed in the enum like A,B,C but also outside ones (C+10, C+11, 3242 ecc.) . I'll use this alias inside traits